# how to perform voice call from one GSM modem to another

Tags: driver, gsm, modem, 3g, mobile-phones

I would like to use a GSM modem to make a voice call from one number to another GSM modem with number. Is it possible and what software can I use for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible assuming you just want to initiate and receive the voice call. You will not be able to process the audio with software.

---

The simplest way to do this is to use [AT commands](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/at-command/info). Assuming the terminating modem has phone number 1234 then on the originating side run `ATD1234;` (notice that the semicolon on the end is required in order to make a voice call. Without it the modem will make a circuit switched data call instead).

Then on the terminating side there are a few ways. The simplest is to set the `S0` register to something different than zero, e.g. `ATS0=2` which will automatically answer an incoming call after two rings (for more details see chapter *6.3.8 Automatic answer* in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en)).

Notice however that `S0` applies to all types of calls, so it would potentially try to answer data calls as well. If you want to be a little bit more sophisticated you could enable the `+CRING` unsolicited result code with `AT+CRC=1` (see [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) for details) and then write a program that monitors UR codes and when receiving `+CRING: VOICE` manually answer the call with `ATA`.

---

Except for the monitoring of UR codes, all the AT command can very easily be sent using the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program. Taking the simplest approach would be on the terminating side to run

```
$ echo ATS0=1 | atinout - /dev/your_modem_device -
ATS0=1

OK
$
```

and on the originating side run

```
$ echo 'AT1234;' | atinout - /dev/your_modem_device -
ATD123;

OK
$
```

Comment: how many usb modems can I connect to one computer if my aim is to emulate as many calls as possible?

Comment: On Linux there are room for 256 `/dev/ttyACM*` devices, and with two allocated per phone should give 128 modems, although there might be other internal limitations that I am not aware of. On windows the answer might be just one if you are unlucky and the driver is very unflexible.